# Shutter delay for camera used with Pi

Tags: camera

I am reading about shutter delay involved with digital cameras [here](https://www.picturecorrect.com/tips/understanding-shutter-delay-in-digital-cameras/).

I checked cameras available for Pi on amazon ([camera1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01ER2SKFS) and [camera2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DNSSDGG)).

I wanted to ask if anyone knows what kind of shutter delay is involved in cameras used with Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Wonder how old that article is as it should be burnt on a fire of lithium batteries.  My old old Canon D10 had less than 0.2 second delay and that was back in 2005 or 2006 when I bought it.

Comment: Is there any more recent article you can recommend ?

Comment: @Andyroo, the wayback machine has first archived that page nov 13, 2009

Comment: @Jake you may find https://www.talkphotography.co.uk/threads/raspberry-pi-sound-trigger.527509/ interesting - it has code for droplet pics that may give you a starting point.  You can set a delay with `raspistill -t` but it may be best to work with the module as it may differ depending on manufacturer, software settings, delays in trigger circuit etc.